# Rename a field with JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I need to rename existing field or drop existing field from a table with jpa. I put hbm2ddl.auto as update. But it is not working. can someone tell me

Answer (score 0):

hbm2ddl.auto will only add columns when in update mode.  it does not drop existing columns.

Comment: Thanks. Can't I drop a column with jpa configurations

Comment: not explicitly using the update configuration.  when you choose "create" option you'll get DDL that drops and creates, but you won't get DDL that can drop an individual column; you'll need to do that.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, @user2579448. Don't forget to accept answers and check out how to format your questions using Stackoverflow markdown.